# ios - why do the screens on the storyboard look different (space inserted) that when I run the program?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I have this screenshot of my storyboard which looks ok, and then the simulator which has some weird whitespace block on the screen.[image]

The simulator is retina 4-inch ios6 simulator.  Is this not a correct simulator? Or is there something else I am doing incorrectly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the 7 bottom right buttons inside your storyboard. Out of those 7 buttons, the one on the extrem left, will toggle your storyboard views for 3.5-inch to 4-inch displays. Since currently your storyboard is set for 3.5-inch display but you are running on a 4-inch simulator, thats the reason for the inconsistency

Comment: hi, I am getting that there is an inconsistency, but where are the buttons that you mentioned? Could you please explain how to navigate to them?

Comment: In your screenshot, the right hand column is the utilities, the left hand column is the navigator, and in the center window the storyboard is open, right? Now look at the bottom right corner of the center storyboard window, you'll see 7 buttons in total, grouped as 1, 3 ,3. The leftmost single button out of those 7, is what I'm talking about

Answer (score 3):

There could be two problems here.

1. Your constrains or springs and struts are set wrong.
2. Inside of Interface Builder your scroll view is scrolled down. If you have more content in a scroll view than what can be held in that scroll view, then you can scroll within that scroll view.

   More than once, I've confused myself because a particularly large table view wasn't showing the table cell prototype I was looking for. My storyboard is big and I would end up hunting around for it until I realized that it's merely scrolled off the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

Retina 4-inch corresponds to iPhone 5 but your storyboard's controllers view are setting for Iphone 3/4